# Can't load textures in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I created a scene with boxes and added textures from .png files to it. It is showed perfect in SceneKit Editor, but after running on device I see no any textures and have this log message for every texture:

> [SceneKit] Error: Failed loading : src:file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A43C8B5A-F58D-4BAC-88BE-22CCF9B52A00/Portfolio.app/app_icons/icon_font%20candy.png [0.000000x0.000000]>

What's wrong? Maybe it is a beta bug? FYI, I use iOS 11 beta 8 (15A5368a) and Xcode 9 beta 6 (9M214v).

Comment: Did you try to remove space from image name?

Comment: Your problem sounds familiar: I think this happened to me before .Do you have a art.scnassets folder?   I keep any images used as a texture maps in that folder typically & then I set the diffuse texture in the Scene Kit materials inspector. I am using iOS 11 beta 9 and Xcode 9 beta 6.   You don't have to use an assets folder but I think it helps if you are creating packed texture maps.

Comment: Yes, I added and .png's to art.scnassets. I realized that the scene tried to find textures in project core folder, not in art.scnassets

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: I don't remember actually. Check out my project https://github.com/rosberry/pARtfolio. Maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Same error happened on me and the fix is, on the .mtl file where you give path to images, use full path such as

```
yourModels.scnasssets/yourFolder/Materials/material.tga
```

My path was
`yourFolder/Materials/material.tga` because the material file was on that folder, but Xcode looks for full path from root.